# Android studio doesn't start its emulator

Tags: intel, android-studio

Last Edit: For the people having the same problem. I've just downloaded official amd gpu driver from amd's site. It's quiet easy actually just download the file extract it cd to inside extracted folder and run the installer script.

I am trying to start emulator inside Android Studio but when I click start nothing happens. I've searched through web and found someone saying I need to install HAXM. But the thing is there is no "Extras" folder in SDK manager in the android studio I'm using. There is no standalone SDK manager option either. I even tried to open SDK manager manually doing:

```
/home/Android/sdk/tools
./android
```

And output was

```
The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
```

Okay then I did

```
cd bin/
./sdkmanager --list
```

And I got the list of all the installed packages and not installed ones. Eventho there were packages whose name were starting with extras I couldn't see Intel HAXM there. What should I do at this point? I really don't want to install another emulator I'd rather use android studio's.

Edit: Forgot to mention that Intel HAXM's repository is in the SDK Update Sites.

More edit: Tried to start emulator via terminal and got the following output

```
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It doesn't seem to be that my problem is with HAXM.